# Using WWW::Mechanize to PUT a JSON message to a server

Tags: json, perl, mechanize

I am trying to use HTTP PUT to send a JSON message to a server but I get an error message:

> Error PUTing https://www.example.com/records: Unprocessable Entity at ./script.pl line 190.

What does this message mean? Is it from Perl or is it from the server (I assume Perl as it gives me a line number).

This is what the script is doing (using the same mechanize objects in all steps):

- GET "www.example.com" (OK)
- POST credentials to the login form (OK)
- GET "https://www.example.com/records" (OK)
- Decode the received JSON (appears OK)
- Create a new JSON string called $json_text (appears OK)
- PUT $json_text to "https://www.example.com/records" (ERROR)

I am using CentOS 7.5 with all updates as of today installed.

Here are extracts from the last two steps.

```
my $json_text;

# Some logic here to fill the string

print $json_text . "\n";
$mech->content_type( 'application/json' );
$mech->put ( $url, content => $json_text );
```

The print statement outputs:

```
{"record":{"webspace":false,"ttl":600,"filter_value":"test.com","abc_record_type":null,"formId":12345678,"standard_value":false,"area":"test.com","address":"12.12.12.12","id":12345678,"type":"A","sub_area":""},"area_lock_state":{"area_locked":false,"email_locked":false}}
```

I don't see anything wrong in the JSON object. Do you have any pointers or on how to use Mechanize to put this object?

Comment: You probably forgot a key or have a typo in one.

Answer (score 2):

[`httpstatuses.com`](https://httpstatuses.com/422)
says this

> The server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a **415 Unsupported Media Type** status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a **400 Bad Request** status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

So the server is happy with the syntax of your JSON but the semantics are invalid. That's all I can say from the information you've given